# Table Transform with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Normally when I deal with SQL (rarely) I only use `SELECT *  FROM` statement all the time. My primary job is working with Excel as an analysis. However, I feel my efficiency can be much improved with programming, I have started to learn some programming (VBA for Excel). Today I want to do something more advantage which is trying to transform a table using Microsoft SQL like attached picture below.

```
SELECT Part_Number as [Part Number], SubPart, Quantity FROM....
```

Bascially, the Part Number can be as many as 200, SubPart only has 3 type Sub-I, Sub-II, and Sub-III,  Quantity can be anything. I need some help to transform the table as shown

[image]

Comment: Do you need to update the headers on your second (transformed) table?  Otherwise I don't get it.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, I updated it sorry for missing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write dynamic T-Sql query as:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)      
       ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @columns = N''
--Get column names for entire pivoting
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(SpreadCol)
  FROM (select distinct Part_Number as SpreadCol 
        from test
       ) AS T
--select @columns
SET @sql = N'
SELECT SubPart, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(select SubPart , Part_Number as SpreadCol ,  Quantity
from test ) as D
PIVOT
(
  sum(Quantity) FOR SpreadCol IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS Pivot1
'
--select @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[Check Fiddle Demo here..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9d55/9)

Comment: thank you very much. I just tested the SQL via Fiddle Demo and worked great. I will try to extend the syntax to fit my problem which is much more complex but similar.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use *Pivoting*.

---

Refer to:

[Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Simple Way To Use Pivot In SQL Query](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query)

Comment: thanks for the link, I basically understand now. However, the problems are: (1) If I do not know the Part Number (2) How many Part Number

Comment: @user2103670 Use dynamic pivoting