# Hide row with all null value using Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I asked a question and the answer came up as I would have to use Dynamic Pivot [Link to Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745148/table-transform-with-sql/24754853#24754853) and I got a great helps. Now, I am trying to get rid of row with all null values but I could not.

*Please note the Column header for Current Result should Be Part 01, Part ABC, and Part 03 (not 0 as shown)
[image]

```
WHERE SubPart IS NOT NULL/ WHERE  Quantity IS NOT NULL
```

but it does not work (well, it still queries but with null values)

After the FROM and from Statements

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)      
       ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @columns = N''
--Get column names for entire pivoting
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(SpreadCol)
  FROM (select distinct Part_Number as SpreadCol 
        from test
       ) AS T
--select @columns
SET @sql = N'
SELECT SubPart, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(select SubPart , Part_Number as SpreadCol ,  Quantity
from test ) as D
PIVOT
(
  sum(Quantity) FOR SpreadCol IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS Pivot1
'
--select @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the where condition to the inner query which is used as the source for piovot and the column list query

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)      
       ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @columns = N''
--Get column names for entire pivoting
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(SpreadCol)
  FROM (select distinct Part_Number as SpreadCol 
        from test WHERE  Quantity IS NOT NULL 
       ) AS T
--select @columns
SET @sql = N'
SELECT SubPart, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(select SubPart , Part_Number as SpreadCol ,  Quantity
from test WHERE  Quantity IS NOT NULL  ) as D
PIVOT
(
  sum(Quantity) FOR SpreadCol IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS Pivot1
'
```

Comment: I did try to put the WHERE QUantity is not null as you did but null values still return

Comment: I tested - if I using the program Navicat then it shows null but I use  SQL Fiddle, then it does not show. Thanks - I guess I got it worked but just not did not realize it