# SQL Query / Yes or No

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and trying to write some queries to assist in analysing some business date.

Two tables

```
**Contacts**

| first_name | last_name | email |

**Events**

| email | event_name | status |
```

I an trying to run a query to output a list of all our contacts and show which event they have or haven't attended. At the moment I can generate the date but it is in two separate reports. Ideally I would like it to look something like this with a yes or no under each event.

```
| email | event#1 | event #2 | event #3 |
```

Here is my current query;

```
SELECT email,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM events
                    WHERE events.email = contacts.email AND events.event_name='Event 1' AND events.status='Show') THEN 'YES'
                    ELSE 'NO'
                    END AS EVENT#1
  FROM contacts
```

It returns the results correctly for event#1, but I can't figure out how to include the other events.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Ps. Sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: Is the number of events finite, if so you could repeat the same that you did for event 1 for the other events as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pivot`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
select 
    email,
    case [event 1] when 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as [event 1],
    case [event 2] when 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as [event 2],
    case [event 3] when 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as [event 3]
from 
(select * from events where status='show') e
pivot 
(count(status) for event_name in ([event 1],[event 2],[event 3])) p
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are filtering your Results on events.event_name = 'Event 1' so it should only be returning Event 1.
If you just want Event 2 and Event 3 as well just do the same When exists subquery
except replace

```
  events.event_name = 'Event 1'
```

with

```
  events.event_name = 'Event 2'
  events.event_name = 'Event 3'
```

in each subquery and then you should get the multiple columns for Event 2 and Event 3.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of event is unknown in advance it's a tricky operation since you are trying to use as columns what effectively are records in the Events table ... this operation is complex and usually it's called pivot. You want to create a columns in your resultset from records in the table (event1, event2, ..., eventN) dinamically.

All databases uses to have something to help with pivot operations but syntax uses to be slightly different, take a look at your rdbms documentation to know how to implement pivot operations in your database.

Otherwise if you know the number of columns (events) or there are only few you can repeat the CASE statement for the other values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using PIVOT queries as below. However if you have many events then you can go for dynamic pivoting. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764940/hide-row-with-all-null-value-using-dynamic-pivot/24765966#24765966)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT Contacts.email,Events.eventname
     ,CASE Events.[status] WHEN 'Show' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Status]
  FROM Contacts
     JOIN Events ON Contacts.email = Events.email
) AS Source
PIVOT
(
    MIN([Status]) 
    FOR eventname IN
    ([event 1],[event 2],[event 3])
) AS PVT ;
```